# How to Treat Entire Phrase as One Search Term and Highlight It in Azure Cognitive Search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

I am using Azure Cognitive Search and need to implement a search functionality that treats the entire phrase "lung cancer" as one search term, highlighting it as a single entity, and allowing for case-insensitive searches. However, I'm facing challenges in achieving this.

Here's what I've tried so far:

I attempted to use the "standard" analyzer, but it didn't work as expected. The standard analyzer tokenizes the phrase into separate words, resulting in undesired highlighting (e.g., *lung* *cancer*).
I also tried the "whitespace" analyzer, but it didn't resolve the issue either. The whitespace analyzer doesn't handle case insensitivity.
I believe a custom analyzer would be the right approach to achieve the desired results. However, I encountered an issue when trying to assign the analyzer using the REST API:

perl
Copy code
"analyzer": {
"@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
"tokenizer": "pattern",
"tokenFilters": ["lowercase"]
},
The above code returned a "405 Method Not Allowed" error.

Could someone please provide a clear and detailed example of how to create a custom analyzer to treat the phrase as a whole, enabling case insensitivity and achieving the correct highlighting behavior? I'd appreciate it if the solution includes REST API calls or other practical approaches to implement the custom analyzer.

Thank you in advance for any insights or guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, you can create a custom analyzer that using the `pattern tokenizer` to treat "lung cancer" as a single term, apply a `lowercase token filter` for case-insensitive searches and add  `"CASE_INSENSITIVE" flag` to get all the results with matching phrase.

I have used below index schema:

```py
"fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "key": True,
      "searchable": False
    },
    {
      "name": "text",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": True,
      "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer"
    }
  ],
  "analyzers": [
    {
      "name": "my_custom_analyzer",
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "tokenizer": "my_pattern_tokenizer",
      "tokenFilters": ["lowercase"]
    }
  ],
  "tokenizers": [
    {
      "name": "my_pattern_tokenizer",
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.PatternTokenizer",
      "pattern": "(lung cancer)",
      "flags": "CASE_INSENSITIVE",
      "group": 1
    }
  ]
```

Uploaded below data to index:

```py
"value": [
    {
      "@search.action": "upload",
      "id": "1",
      "text": "Lung cancer is a serious condition."
    },
    {
      "@search.action": "upload",
      "id": "2",
      "text": "Smoking is a major cause of lung cancer."
    },
    {
      "@search.action": "upload",
      "id": "3",
      "text": "Lung Cancer treatments have improved over the years."
    }
  ]
```

The sample consist of three entries with different pattern of the phrase.

With below search query:

```py
{
  "search": "\"lung cancer\"",
  "highlight": "text",
  "highlightPreTag": "<b>",
  "highlightPostTag": "</b>"
}
```

With above Index Schema, I  was able to get the result with "lung cancer " as single term highlighted.
[image]
Complete output:

```py
{
  "@odata.context": "https://service-name.search.windows.net/indexes('pattern15')/$metadata#docs(*)",
  "value": [
    {
      "@search.score": 0.2876821,
      "@search.highlights": {
        "text": [
          "<b>Lung Cancer</b> treatments have improved over the years."
        ]
      },
      "id": "3",
      "text": "Lung Cancer treatments have improved over the years."
    },
    {
      "@search.score": 0.2876821,
      "@search.highlights": {
        "text": [
          "Smoking is a major cause of <b>lung cancer</b>."
        ]
      },
      "id": "2",
      "text": "Smoking is a major cause of lung cancer."
    },
    {
      "@search.score": 0.2876821,
      "@search.highlights": {
        "text": [
          "<b>Lung cancer</b> is a serious condition."
        ]
      },
      "id": "1",
      "text": "Lung cancer is a serious condition."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This works. But, I want to use for any search term and not just "lung cancer". The user can input any search term into the search bar and this should work. I tried using the accept-al (".*") regex in tokenizers[0].pattern but then I was unable to push in the search field accurately. I have these fields (https://codeshare.io/AdPMXE) in the search service and I would like to apply full text search on the content field. With this regex, while trying to insert a document, the content field was always null.